# Create a fibonacci sequences using for-loop and arrays in java

Tags: java, arrays

Generate a Fibonacci sequence.

- Each number in the Fibonacci sequence is the
  sum of the two preceding numbers in the sequence.
- The first two numbers in the sequence are both 1.
- The third number is 2 , the fourth number is 3, the fifth number is 5, and the sixth number is 8.
- The program should
  be able to return a specified number in the fibo sequence.
- If a number is specified that is out of range, a -1
  should be returned.

The starting of code:

```
 public class Fibonacci
 {
  public static int[] go(int[] ray)
  {
   int [] array = int[];
    array[0] = 0;
    array[1] = 1;
    for(int i = 2; i<ray.length; i++)
    {
      array[i] = array[i-1] + array[i-2];
    }  
    return array; 
  }
}
```

The Runner that i use with this program:

```
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Fibonacci rt = new Fibonacci();
    //Set size to 50
    System.out.println( rt.go(1,50));
    System.out.println( rt.go(2,50));
    System.out.println( rt.go(3,50));
    System.out.println( rt.go(4,50));
    System.out.println( rt.go(5,50));
    System.out.println( rt.go(6,50));
    System.out.println( rt.go(11,50));
    System.out.println( rt.go(16,50));
    System.out.println( rt.go(21,50));
    System.out.println( rt.go(31,50));
    System.out.println( rt.go(41,50));
    System.out.println( rt.go(46,50));
    //Set size to 1
    System.out.println( rt.go(1,1));
    //Set size to 2
    System.out.println( rt.go(1,2));
    System.out.println( rt.go(2,2));
    System.out.println( rt.go(11,2));
  }
}
```

Correct answers with this runner:

```
1
1
2
3
5
8
89
987
10946
1346269
165580141
1836311903
1
1
1
-1
```

Please anyone correct my code because it do not work but do not change the concept that i use.

Thank you

Comment: what's wrong with that code?? You have not tell us what's the problem

Comment: Your logic for generating the Fibonacci sequence seems generally correct.   However, the line int [] array = int[];` is just plain wrong. What did you have in mind to accomplish there?  Perhaps you meant to write `int[] array = new int[ray.length];`?

Comment: @KevinAnderson Thank you and one more problem i run this code but it says "method go in class Fibonacci cannot be applied to given types"

Answer (score 0):

1. The method is supposed to take two int arguments `k` and `n`.  `k` is the `kth` one to return and `n` is the number to generate.
2. The method is supposed to return an an `int` which would be the `kth` fibonacci.  You are returning the entire array which is incorrect.
3. If k is > than n you are supposed to return a -1.

So you need to make those changes and then run the code to see if it is working.